# can i use common adapter for different list view

Tags: android

My application is a bunch of `ListView`s (with a img, title, desc), for each `Activity` I am just subclassing the `ListActivity` and I am implementing corresponding custom `Adapter` that is on coding side, on layout side i'm defining a list layout, another layout for individual row for each screen.

After implementing 2-3 screens, I thought of reusing my exising layouts and Adapter.

Can anybody suggest the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your are doing the custom adapter but I guess it's an `ArrayAdapter<Something>`.

What you can do is creating an `interface`. Something like:

```
public interface Model {

 int getImage();
 String getTitle();
 String getDescription();

}
```

Make your classes implement that interface and use the interface inside the adapter to bind the data to the view.

Comment: Hi Macarse, I am using my custom ArrayAdapter by overriding getView() method. I am maintaining a List of my Model's as a member of this adapter and preparing a convertView for each list item.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to use common adapters depending on the data your are displaying .

Edit :

Basically one way to do it is build the data you want to display outside the adapter and then pass to the adapter . So your activities can build data as long as they are nearly similar and pass your adapter :-) . You can even pass flags to adapter which you can use in your adapter to conditionally hide data.